# SED change only start of line and preserve end of line

Tags: sed, regular-expression

Basically I have a situation where I frequently need to modify my hosts file to access different servers at my workplace. In an attempt to automate the process. I've been trying to use `sed` to make the changes I need. Basically I am trying to preserve the whole line for some IP's and comment out other IP's.

For IP's that start with `10.4.` To uncomment via `sed`, I've attempted this

```
sed -i '/#10\.4\..*/c\10\.4\..*' /etc/hosts
```

which replaced all the matching lines with `10.4..*` instead of preserving the whole line. I've also attempted this in an attempt to use a group/match:

```
sed -i '/#10\.4\.(.*)/c\10\.4\.\1' /etc/hosts
```

but this just silently fails without making any changes at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove comments from lines that have an IP starting with `10.4` (this will remove the first `#`, I am assuming you will never have more):

```
sed -i '/^#10\.4/{s/^#//}' /etc/hosts
```

To add a comment to those lines:

```
sed -i '/^10\.4/{s/^/#/}' /etc/hosts
```

---

So, why was yours failing? You were using `c\` which means:

> c\
>   text
>
> Delete the lines matching the address or address-range, and output the lines of text which follow this command (each but the last ending with a \, which are removed from the output) in place of the last line (or in place of each line, if no addresses were specified). A new cycle is started after this command is done, since the pattern space will have been deleted.

So, when you ran `sed -i '/#10\.4\..*/c\10\.4\..*' /etc/hosts`, this meant "replace `#10\.4\..*` with the literal string `#10\.4\..*`". What you *wanted* to do is:

```
sed -i 's/#10\.4\.\(.*\)/10.4.\1/' /etc/hosts`
```

The above uses a substitution operator (`s/from/to/`) and pattern capturing, the first pattern in `\( \)` can be referred to as `\1`, the second as `\2` etc. As you can see from Michael's answer this is not needed either, you can just replace `#10.4` with `10.4`. Or, as in my answer above, you can simply remove the `#` alone.

Comment: For removing the comment, I'd be conservative and add an `^` anchor in both regexes, in case the file has `210.4.5.6  foobar  # this is a host`

Comment: @glennjackman good point. That's how I had it originally but then though of cases where there were leading spaces. Still, comments after the IP are very likely as you point out so answer edited, thanks.

Comment: Fantastic, this all makes a lot of sense. One question I have, should the first command really be `sed -i '/^10\.4/{s/^#//}' /etc/hosts`? I think it might need to be `sed -i '/^#10\.4/{s/^#//}' /etc/hosts` in order to find lines that start with a `#`.

Comment: @SonofLysander yes, you're quite right, that was a mistake. Fixed now.

Comment: Cooool, thanks again for all your help. This has made changing my hosts file trivial :)

Answer (score 3):

If all you want is to remove `#` from lines that start `#10.4.`, you can use an `s` command, which replaces matching regular expressions with the given replacement text and leaves the rest of the line unchanged. Either of these work:

```
$ sed -i 's/^#10\.4\./10.4./' /etc/hosts
$ sed -i -r 's/^#(10\.4\.)/\1/' /etc/hosts
```